# How do I change the display of the RevolutionPlot3D of the Z direction?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Im using Revoultion Plot 3d and I'm looking for a way to change the Z bound.(like for exsample only graphing from the height of 1000-5000) These are my commands. So far I have only been able to figure out how to change the display amount of the x axis(via g[x] and the y axis using the PlotRange.

```
g[x_] = 10000E^-(x/1000)^2
RevolutionPlot3D[g[x], {x, -5000, 5000}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe set `PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {1000, 5000}}`.

```
[x_] = 10000 E^-(x/1000)^2;
RevolutionPlot3D[g[x], {x, -5000, 5000}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {1000, 5000}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
g[x_] = 10000 E^-(x/1000)^2
RevolutionPlot3D[g[x], {x, -5000, 5000}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}
 , PlotPoints -> 100
 , MaxRecursion -> 3
 , Exclusions -> None
 , RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, t, θ, r}, 1000 < z < 5000]
 ]
```

[image]